# Compare Dates using NSPredicate to retrieve objects that meet criteria

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to filter an NSArray of objects according to values in a specific key. My objects have a date when they were created, so basically, I want to create objects for three months, but show only one per week, therefore, I need to filter the results to show the objects according to the date.

I have a database with all the information I need to create these objects. My first idea was to create a period key in this database, specifying how long the object will be available. For example, object 1 would have the number 604800 (timeInterval for one week) in the "period"key. Now, for retrieving these objects, I would need to compare two keys, the createdAt, which is an `NSDate`, and the timeInterval which would be a `NSNumber`.

I tried to create two `NSDate`columns in my table and use predicate: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"(startDate <= %@) AND (endDate >= %@"), today, today];`, and although I would have a lot more work to create the objects with these two added columns, the mentioned predicate didn't work, I'm not sure why.

Anyway, I'm looking for a simple solution and some code as well.

Comment: Your `"` look misplaced.. check them once

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typing mistake, but wasn't the problem.

Comment: If you are passing `today` two times (`<=` and `>=`), wouldn't that give you only exact equality (`==`)?

Comment: What is the structure(properties and it classes) of objects stored in the array? May be you need change predicate to `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.startDate <= %@) AND (SELF.endDate >= %@)", today, today];` or use `sortedArrayUsingFunction:`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create and fill extra columns, because you can do simple arithmetic
in the predicate, for example:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt <= %@ AND createdAt + period >= %@", today, today]
```

where `createdAt` is a "Date" attribute and `period` a "Double" attribute.

*Update:* As I just realized, this works only if you also set

```
[request setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];
```

which means that the fetch is executed against the saved database only, but does
not include unsaved changes.

Comment: That is what I am looking for. I'll try and give feedback. Seems like it will work.

Comment: App crashes with message `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. My period is a `NSNumber`, I'm not sure if that might be the problem. If it is, is it possible to convert it to `double` in the `NSPredicate`?

Comment: @Jorge: I tested it with `NSDate *createdAt; NSNumber *period;` and it worked. Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b551d50'`And here is my code: `NSPredicate *predicateTime = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt <= %@ AND createdAt + diasSerieAtiva >= %@", hoje, hoje];`where `createdAt`is `NSDate`and `diasSeriesAtiva`os `NSNumber`, both columns in my database table.

Comment: I have two objects with the number 604800 in the `diasSerieAtiva`column, and `createdAt`column, both objects have 2013-12-26T18:26:20.721Z.

Comment: @Jorge: I have updated the answer. It seems that my proposed solution works only if the query is executed against the SQLite database. If that is not acceptable for you, you have to compute the "endDate" for each object and use that in the predicate. Alternatively, you can fetch first and then filter the result set using a block-based predicate.